# some css properties are not applied while using javafx 8

Tags: css, javafx

When I was using jdk1.7 and javafx 2 my css was working properly but when I upgraded my jdk version to 1.8 some css properties are working and some are not.

For example as in fxml I have used button and its style class as .newRedButton which is defined in css. As in .newRedButton various properties are defined like padding background-color etc.so in my case only 3 properties are applied padding,size and text-fill,rest of the properties(background-image) are not applied. below is the css along with fxml

```
       .newRedButton {
    -fx-padding: 4 0 2 0;
    -fx-background-color: #c1272d;
    -fx-background-radius: 3px;
    -fx-font-family:'QuicksandBold-Regular';
    -fx-font-size: 14;
    -fx-text-fill:#c1272d;
}


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox" fx:id="noCardSelectedRegion" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <padding>
        <Insets top="156"/>
    </padding>
    <HBox alignment="CENTER">
        <HBox fx:id="thumbnailBox" styleClass="thumbnailBox" prefWidth="65" prefHeight="65"
              alignment="CENTER"/>
    </HBox>
    <HBox fx:id="flightPlannerMsgBox" styleClass="flightPlannerMsgBox" alignment="CENTER">
        <Label fx:id="flightPlannerMsg" prefWidth="300" styleClass="flightPlannerMsg"
               text="Insert SD card"/>
    </HBox>
    <HBox fx:id="buttonGroup" styleClass="buttonGroup" spacing="8" alignment="CENTER">

        <Button fx:id="buttonSelectSDCard"
                defaultButton="false"
                styleClass="newRedButton"
                text="SELECT CARD"
                onAction="#onSelectCard"
                minWidth="120"
                prefWidth="150"
                prefHeight="35"/>
    </HBox>
</fx:root>
```

Comment: Try the Developer toolbar to inspect what is going on. You'll have some more insights.

Comment: Actually I am using IntelliJIDEA IDE

Comment: Ok, so do you see any of the properties of the styles being attached to the item? Is the style sheet loaded on page load? OR is it missing?

Comment: I think stylesheet is loading because some of the properties are applied like padding and -fx-text-fill.

Comment: Its done actually it was happening because of some CSS had overridden.